# Ошибка авторизации

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему я получаю сообщение об ошибке когда на моём компьютере нету пользователя, которым я пытаюсь пройти удалённую авторизацию? Как не имея на моём компьютере этого пользователя получить доступ?

```
IntPtr userToken = IntPtr.Zero;

bool success = LogonUser(
   "User",
   null,
   "Password",
   2,
   0,
   out userToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

public static extern bool LogonUser(
   string lpszUsername,
   string lpszDomain,
   string lpszPassword,
   int dwLogonType,
   int dwLogonProvider,
   out IntPtr phToken);
```

Comment: Добавьте больше деталей. Хотя бы текст ошибки

Comment: @Anatol Зачем вам текст ошибки, когда тут понятно, что я пытаюсь авторизоваться на удалённой машине не с тем типом авторизации!

Comment: кому это понятно, кроме вас?

Answer (score -2):

Ошибка была в неправильном типе авторизации. `dwLogonType` нужно было указать `9`.